# Moshi: Expected a Class, ParameterizedType, or GenericArrayType, but <null> is of type null

Tags: android, kotlin, moshi

I have this model:

```
class Model1 {
    <... other fields here ...>
    var attributes: Map<String, Any>? = null
    <... other fields here ...>
}
```

I expect a list of these models.

Sample JSON:

```
[
    {
        "attributes": {
            "title": "New Year's Day",
            "country": "SG"
        }
    },
    {
        "attributes": {
            "staff_id": 320011,
            "title": "Labor day",
            "date_joined": "2017-01-10 00:00:00",
            "years": 1
        }
    }
]
```

Then I get this error during deserialization:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected a Class, ParameterizedType, or GenericArrayType, but <null> is of type null
    at com.squareup.moshi.Types.getRawType(Types.java:165)
    at com.squareup.moshi.ClassJsonAdapter$1.createFieldBindings(ClassJsonAdapter.java:82)
    at com.squareup.moshi.ClassJsonAdapter$1.create(ClassJsonAdapter.java:74)
    at com.squareup.moshi.Moshi.adapter(Moshi.java:99)
    at com.squareup.moshi.Moshi.adapter(Moshi.java:57)
    at com.squareup.moshi.MapJsonAdapter.<init>(MapJsonAdapter.java:46)
    at com.squareup.moshi.MapJsonAdapter$1.create(MapJsonAdapter.java:37)
    at com.squareup.moshi.Moshi.adapter(Moshi.java:99)
    at com.squareup.moshi.ClassJsonAdapter$1.createFieldBindings(ClassJsonAdapter.java:90)
    at com.squareup.moshi.ClassJsonAdapter$1.create(ClassJsonAdapter.java:74)
    at com.squareup.moshi.Moshi.adapter(Moshi.java:99)
    at com.squareup.moshi.Moshi.adapter(Moshi.java:57)
    at com.squareup.moshi.CollectionJsonAdapter.newArrayListAdapter(CollectionJsonAdapter.java:51)
    at com.squareup.moshi.CollectionJsonAdapter$1.create(CollectionJsonAdapter.java:35)
    at com.squareup.moshi.Moshi.adapter(Moshi.java:99)
    at com.squareup.moshi.ClassJsonAdapter$1.createFieldBindings(ClassJsonAdapter.java:90)
    at com.squareup.moshi.ClassJsonAdapter$1.create(ClassJsonAdapter.java:74)
    at com.squareup.moshi.Moshi.adapter(Moshi.java:99)
    at retrofit2.converter.moshi.MoshiConverterFactory.responseBodyConverter(MoshiConverterFactory.java:91)
    at retrofit2.Retrofit.nextResponseBodyConverter(Retrofit.java:330)
    at retrofit2.Retrofit.responseBodyConverter(Retrofit.java:313)
    at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.createResponseConverter(ServiceMethod.java:736)
        ... 65 more
```

I need the field attribute to be a map. The data inside could be any type and any value

Comment: There is similar issue on github https://github.com/square/moshi/issues/309 You can take a look at the PR

Comment: try with using `Any?` instead of `Any`

Comment: @zaid Yes tried already. same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just need to do this:

```
class Model1 {
    <... other fields here ...>
    @JvmSuppressWildcards var attributes: Map<String, Any>? = null
    <... other fields here ...>
}
```

https://github.com/square/moshi/issues/410#issuecomment-351131524

Answer (score 6):

You want `@JvmSuppressWildcards` on the Map parameters.
https://github.com/square/moshi/issues/410#issuecomment-351131524

Hopefully, a better error message will show up in the next version of Moshi.